# how to detect android soft navigation with javascript/jquery/jquerymobile (triangle button, closing keyboard button)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, web-applications, keyboard

I'm trying to hide bottom menu on active android keyboard.
The main logic what I'm thinking of is using jQuery focus and blur events to toggle displaying fixed bottom menu.
(fixed bottom menu is show or hide when occured focus / blur event)

But I need to know how to handle closing android keyboard by navigation of android software (smartphone / tablet etc) to prevent unexpected bugs.

Thanks for any input or suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can't even tell that with native code.  There's no API for being informed of the soft keyboard being opened/closed.